# GWT. What tools have GWT to calculate commission 18%?

Tags: gwt, number-formatting

How I can calculate commission 18% in GWT? I can simply multiply it by 0.18, but i think it don't normally for money and scientific calculations. I need accurate result, with accurate rounding.

Thanks.

Comment: What data type are you using for the sum?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are concerned about accurate results then you should not use float or double for currencies. These data types are inherently inaccurate. You can't display a lot of decimal values with them so rounding is pointless. They are unsuited for currencies.

Use `BigDecimal` for this purpose. The class has mathematical operations that return exact values in form of another `BigDecimal`. Supported in GWT since version 2.1.

For scientific calculations you need to know about the exactness of floating point types. It is not constant over the range of values. It depends on the circumstances if these types are appropriate.

Comment: sry, i cant find this class in official  docs. Can you point me? Or you mean third-party gwt-math library?

Comment: Just `java.math.BigDecimal`. The library you mention was needed before `BigDecimal` was available in GWT's JVM emulation.